# one client chat to another

Tags: java, chat

I have created a simple Java chat program, which provides one server and multiple clients.
But I only can make it where all clients can talk (the messages was sent to all clients).
I need to make a private chat beside the public chat I've made.
E.g: computerA just wants to chat with computerB, but computerA still can talk with all clients. How can I do this?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How one client to one another client chat in java?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6001172/how-one-client-to-one-another-client-chat-in-java)

Comment: please don't post the same question twice. go back to your previous question and add more details there.

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way to do it is to modify your protocol a little bit to include some information whether the message you are sending is a public (everyone can see it) or a private one (just user A and user B talking).

With that information in hand, in the server, whenever you find a private message, just send it to the one and only destination expecting that message. Do not try to do some peer to peer stuff because you will encounter many problems along the way.

Other small variation of this solution would be supporting "private rooms" on your chat server. But that will be a little bit more complicated to implement.